Microsoft Excel VBA Save As CSV Subroutine - File Cannot Be Accessed Error
For an end user on my team the following subroutine fails to save a CSV file with an error message that states "'OUTLOOK MERGE DATA.CSV' cannot be accessed. The file may be corrupted, located on a server that is not responding, or read-only."
I have included the error message as a screenshot, and the subroutine for reference.
Error Message:

Private Sub SAVE()
'
' Creating a new book in which to place schedules

USID = Environ("UserName")
 
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\" & (USID) & "\Desktop\" & "OUTLOOK MERGE DATA" & ".CSV", FileFormat:=xlCSV, _
        CreateBackup:=False
        
    ActiveWorkbook.SAVE
    ActiveWindow.Close
    
End Sub

I have yet to be able to reproduce the same error on my end when I run the full VBA module and have not been able to find any answers online that suggest a similar experience/solution. I am definitely very confused, because the subroutine is generating a new file, so why would it be attempting to access something existing? If anyone here has had any similar experiences with Excel VBA, I would greatly appreciate advisement on the solution you found.
Thank you!

Is that same user able to manually save a similar file from within Excel?   Are they using a Mac?

Thank you for a prompt reply Tim!
I have yet to try that with them, I am not a VBA/Software Dev expert by any means. However, it would be worth exploring a stop at the SAVE sub to see if we can't manually save it as a CSV after the other subs have completed their processing. I'll get with the end user and try your suggestion in troubleshooting and post a response once I have. More to follow...

They are not on a mac either, btw. We all use Dell laptops in our corporate environment.

It probably has something to do with your Windows environment.  I can reproduce the error when trying to save to the local desktop.  Seems that the company policies don't even allow me to do so, and everything is re-directed to OneDrive.  Your code works fine when using other system folders so I would suggest just not using desktop as the destination and everything should work fine.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

@TimWilliams We were able to save the file as a CSV manually. I believe that Michal is probably correct in that this issue is stemming from connections to OneDrive when the subroutine attempts to save the file to the user's desktop. Going to try and manipulate the code to either path directly to a OneDrive path or some other path outside of OneDrive on the user's hardware.
Thank you all for the supporting comments here as I work on a solution for my team.
Cheers!

Try this;
USID = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop")

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=USID & "\OUTLOOK MERGE DATA", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False


Thank you for this trick! It seemed to work on my end. However, in the past this VBA would automatically select Save when prompted and close the active window. When I swapped the two lines of code you provided, it appears that the latter two lines to Save and Close the active window no longer function proper. Any ideas?
